# getting controller route parameter

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-3.3

Using Kohana 3.3, I created a tabbed interface and I'm trying to detect which tab is active based on a route parameter.

Testing with 2 urls which look like this: `mysite.com/p/mycontroll`
and: `mysite.com/p/Francis-Lewis/mycontroll`

My route looks like this:

```
Route::set('profile', 'p(/<name>)(/<controller>(/<action>))', array(
        'name'          => '[\w\-]+',
        'controller'    => '[a-z]+',
        'action'        => '(view|edit|save|delete|create|cancel)',
    ))->defaults(array(
        'name'          => null,
        'directory'     => 'profile',
        'controller'    => 'main',
        'action'        => 'index',
    ));
```

The route itself is working fine, selecting the `mycontroll` controller.
Here's where the problem comes in.
In the controller:

```
$this->request->param('controller'); // returns NULL
```

In the view

```
<?= Request::current()->param('controller') ?> // returns NULL
```

After banging my head around for a while, I added a function to the Kohana Request class to return the `$_params` array to see what was in there.

Here's all it returns:

```
name => 'Francis Lewis'
```

Any ideas how to get the current controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function for that in in the request object:

```
$this->request->controller(); // Returns the current controller as a String
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are absolutely sure that you want the initial controller then you can use the next method:

```
Request::initial()->controller();
```

otherwise use this method:

```
Request::current()->controller();
```